# Duvida quanto a criação de maps de eventos - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, array, typescript

Sou estagiário e assumi um projeto em uma linguagem que não tenho muito conhecimento, estou tendo problemas a criar um retorno de eventos, tentei procurar erros parecidos na internet, mas sem sucesso. Segue o erro:

[![Imagem que mostra onde o erro ocorre][1]][1]

E o código:

```
return api.post<Response, apiEvent[]>('execute', data).then(() => {
  const events: IEvent[] = response.map((item: apiEvent): IEvent[] => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Outro erro que da em `events` é:

> ```
> Type 'IEvent[][]' is not assignable to type 'IEvent[]'.
> ```

Se algum puder tentar me explicar o motivo do erro agradeceria muito.

Answer (score 1):

O *callback* do `map` não retorna um array de `IEvent`, mas sim um `IEvent`.

Troque a anotação de retorno do *callback* de `IEvent[]` para `IEvent`. O *array* de tipo `IEvent[]` é retornado por *todo* o `map`, de modo que cada *callback* só retorna um evento.

- [Saiba mais sobre o `Array.prototype.map`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

---

Mas ao corrigir o erro acima, um outro erro surgirá:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include `'undefined'`.

Isso acontece porque, quando você define uma anotação explícita de retorno de função, o TypeScript verificará se todos os *code paths* retornarão o tipo que você especificou explicitamente.

Pense neste exemplo:

```
function sum(a: number, b: number | undefined): number {
  if (b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  // O TypeScript irá reclamar, uma vez que, se `b` não estiver
  // definido, este caminho não retornará nada (no caso, um número
  // não será retornado). Desse modo, como anotamos explicitamente
  // o retorno da função como `number`, o erro ocorre.
}
```

Para corrigir o erro, então, você deve garantir que todos os caminhos retornem o tipo especificado por você.

Comment: eu fiz como você disse, porém o erro que aprensentei na imagem persistiu. O código está assim: 

`return api.post<Response, apiEvent[]>('execute', data).then(() => { const events: IEvent[] = response.map((item: apiEvent): IEvent => { // ... }); });`

Comment: Estranho... Poderia tentar então reproduzir o **mesmo** problema no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) e colar o link na sua pergunta, por favor? cc: @Jonatan

Comment: Feito, @LuizFelipe